# How is stereo audio data recorded using IAudioCaptureClient?

Tags: audio-recording, wasapi

I am recording stereo audio from line-in of the desktop using Microsoft's Core Audio API. It records at 44100Hz, 32 bit. I want to know how the stereo data is recorded into the buffer, like is it first 32 bit is of one microphone and next 32 bit is of second microphone or something else?[Here is the code I used to record audio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/coreaudio/capturing-a-stream)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the channels are interleaved. So your buffer should look like this:  [left 16 bits][right 16 bits][left 16 bits][right 16 bits] ... [left 16 bits][right 16 bits].